# how to use a different shell when changing to root

Tags: shell, su

I have some personal settings in my user shell e.g: `.vimrc` and `.bash_profile` and other stuff.

is it possible to switch to root using `su -` but at the same time use the profile from my user?

Comment: Keep in mind the security implications if you do this.  It *can* be a very bad idea.  I recommend explicitly setting the individual settings you want to have as `root` rather than keeping your full user profile settings.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` tells `su` to source the target user's profile and environment. If you want to retain your old environment (i.e. your user's environment), simply leave off the `-` and just use `su`. Of course, any path components unique to the root user will then not be present and will have to be added manually.

Comment: Note that `$HOME` may still be changed and so `$HOME/.vimrc` will still point to the `root` version.

Comment: this worked partially. the .bash_profile seemed to be loaded from my user but the alias in that file were not loaded

Answer (score 2):

`su -` means "switch to root, and run it as a login shell" (also `su -l` and `su --login`).

Now even without the `-` the `$HOME` variable will be set and so `$HOME/.vimrc` will point to the `root` version.

What we need is the `--preserve-environment` option.

```
su --preserve-environment
```

This will run a root shell but will leave `$HOME` untouched and will run your own shell (eg if you use `ksh` or `zsh`) and will run your dot files

eg

```
$ su --preserve-environment  
Password: 
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# echo $HOME
/home/sweh
# echo $0
ksh
#
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert this into root's `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` whichever is more convenient and available.

```
profile=anand # let's assume this is your user name
myorigusername=$(who am i | awk {'print $1'})
if [ "${myorigusername}" = "${profile}" ]
then
  cd ~${myorigusername}
  . ./.vimrc
  . ./.bash_profile
  # other stuff here
fi
```

If you need any explanation, just ask, or better, test it on your system.

Comment: I don't want to edit root files as they are shared by all users on our servers. that is why i want it to source it from my profile when i login using 'su'

Comment: This will only run when **you** logged in as _anand_ user. Others will not be affected. But you can run whatever you want, which is in the `if .. then` block, manually after you login as well.

Comment: i tried this. For loading the vimrc it threw several command not found errors. e.g. bash: :syntax: command not found from the vimrc file